# Iteratively open files in a folder and run a subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to iteratively open every Excel file in a selected folder and then run a series of subroutines on each file. I originally developed the macro (lazily named Main) that opens a single file and performs the appropriate actions - this sub works just fine as far as I can tell.

I'm now working on building a sub called FolderPicker that will open each file in a selected folder and then run the Main sub.

Currently, I have this code, adapted from https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder

```
    Sub FolderPicker()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  MyFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While MyFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & MyFile)
    vFileName = myPath & MyFile
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
    
    'Run main sub
      main
    
    'Ensure main has completed
      DoEvents
    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Activate
      wb.Close savechanges:=False
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      MyFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The beginning of this macro runs just fine, the folder dialog box works, and it opens the first file. However, the MyFile = Dir line directly proceeding Loop doesn't seem to be working - it evaluates to a null value and then the sub ends. I've verified that there are multiple files in the folder.

For reference, vFileName is a publicly declared variant that's used in Main.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you share the `main` procedure?

Comment: Does the code in `main` make use of `Dir()` ?  If it did then it would definitely be relevant...  Ideally `main` would at least have a parameter of type `Workbook` to which you could pass in `wb` as an argument.

Comment: @TimWilliams It does and I just now realized that that's the issue. I wasn't aware that Dir() didn't work recursively. I'll switch to FSO. Thanks, and if you submit that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @chris neilsen: How about `vFileName = myPath & MyFile`? Would you really use this, and especially as a public variable in your code? Or would you rather use it as an argument (probably just `MyFile`) in the `main` procedure?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, I would pass the path/filename or the workbook to Main, but thats _not_ what the OP was asking about.  FWIW, Tim nailed it, and invalidated my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use nested `Dir()` loops, so if `main` also uses `Dir()` then you'll need to take a different approach, such as adding all the matches from the outer `Dir()` to a Collection and then looping over that to call `main` on each match.